# ASP MVC 5 - Extending Identity 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I have the following `ApplicationUser` class, is there a way to add a claim or extend identity so that I can check if user is in a project group by doing something like: `User.Identity.IsInProjectGroup(1)`.

Currently I have to keep going into the database to get the user and then call the `IsInProjectGroup` method.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Groups = new Collection<Group>();
    } 

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }

    public bool IsInProjectGroup(int projectId)
    {
        return Groups.Any(g => g.Projects.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(projectId));

    }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
       var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

       // how do you add claim???
       userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Group", ???));

       return userIdentity;
     }

 }
```

Is there a way to add a claim to call a method or is there another way to achieve this?

I was thinking of an extension as follows but unsure of how I add such a claim inside my `ApplicationUser` class and how to check the claim in the extension method below:

```
namespace App.Extensions
{
   public static class IdentityExtensions
   {
       public static bool IsInProjectGroup(this IIdentity identity, int projectId)
       {
           // how would i do the check here???
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Just add the claim to the identity when creating it.

Comment: @Nkosi can you show with some code please?

Comment: I was writing up an answer but then you changed the code. Are you looking for groups or projects? Clarify what it is you want exactly.

Comment: @Nkosi my apologies it is projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example.

First create a constant to use as a key for the claim

```
public class Constants { 
    public class Security {
        public class ClaimTypes
            public const string ProjectGroups = "ProjectGroups";
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can create the claims when creating your identity

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager) {
   var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
   // how do you add claim???
   if(Groups.Any()) { //assuming this is a navigation property
       //create a claim type/name/key
       //replace with you desired key. Store in a constant for later use
       var claimName = Constants.Security.ClaimTypes.ProjectGroup; 
       //create claims from current groups.
       var claims = Groups.SelectMany(g => g.Projects.Select(x => x.Id))
           .Select(id => new System.Security.Claims.Claim(claimName, id.ToString()));
       userIdentity.AddClaims(claims);
   }
   return userIdentity;
 }
```

For retrieval you can create you own extension method to check the groups within the claim itself and not hit the database.

```
public static class IdentityExtensions {
    public static bool IsInProjectGroup(this IIdentity identity, int projectId) {
       // how would i do the check here???
       if(identity != null) {
            var claimsIdentity = identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            if (claimsIdentity != null) {
                return claimsIdentity
                    .FindAll(Constants.Security.ClaimTypes.ProjectGroups)
                    .Any(claim => claim.Value == projectId.ToString());
            }
       }
       return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your code but no claims seem to get added. I logged out and logged back in and when I try calling `User.Identity.IsInProjectGroup(1)` in my controller it is always false. I've checked the UserClaims table in the database and that is also empty. Any ideas what could be happening?

Comment: @adam78 Well that pertains to what you are storing in the Groups property. My assumption was that Groups was populated. The code is sound. If there is no data then it will obviously be empty.

Comment: is my understanding of claims correct - do they get stored inside the UserClaims table or only as a cookie? I've tried adding the following as a test: `userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("FirstName", FirstName));` and that doesn't get stored inthe UserClaims table either?

Comment: Ok storing the claims in the db in totally separate. You will need to read up the docs to get a better understanding of how they are persisted. Out of scope here. I was showing you how to add them to the identity and retrieve them once added. they are all in-memory. not saved to db.

Comment: no I dont need to store them in the database, I was merely asking. How can I can check if the claim exists in the cookie then - so for example if ii add the following: `userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("FirstName", FirstName));` how can I check if this has been saved?

Comment: after you create your identity you should then login the user with that identity. and make sure remember me is set to true.

Comment: I'm using `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync()` to login user so so do I still need to create identity - I thought `SignInManager` took care of creating the identity  if the claims are added to `ApplicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync()` method?

Comment: @adam78 this question is starting to morph from the original scope and appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). . I would suggest we resolve the original question then create a new question with what your actual goal is so that it can be answered.